# Good CSS table theming tool?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

It's been a long time since I've styled a table. I've got three different tables I need to style that all are going to use the same basic colors etc, but are all different shapes/sizes.

I'm wondering if anyone knows a good library or tool for generating nice html/css tables from JSON or something (you feed some JS or PHP a data structure, JSON or Arrays, and it spits out an HTML/CSS table)? Yes, I'm using them for tabular data (they are pricing sheets). Or if there is a good non-table driven alternative for displaying tabular data, I'm all ears...

Here's an example of what the background portion of the table is going to look like. Each table is going to have a different statically "highlighted" column (or none at all); this is not a hover effect, just a called out column.

[image]

Comment: just use one sprite image and play with the css. thats the best option

Comment: I started going down that path, but I just felt like someone out there had to have created a library or something for doing this sort of thing...

Comment: Also, you can't really do tiling with sprite images, so, while I could use a sprite for all the corner pieces; the pieces that need tiled would have to be their own individual images...

Comment: You can see what I came up with in the end here: http://www1.instantcustomer.com/pricing/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's another try: http://jsfiddle.net/wwntH/4/

[image]

Comment: +1 even you use a little bit different colors, it's great and result and css. Well done

Comment: @Sotoris: I have no easy way of finding the colors. Paint doesn't tell you what color is picked up by the eyedropper.

Comment: @Sotoris: Yep, I just found that. On chrome though, and a chrome extension would clutter my toolbar. Unless someone has a right click and grab color chrome extension.

Comment: +1, I like it. It's not exactly what I'm looking for, but it looks really good. If I can't find a library/framework, this will probably end up being a good starting point for me making my own. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for awesomeness. Some day when I grow up, I want to be able to do css like that.

Comment: @Eric: Can I ask why are you using 7 <colgroup> instead of 7 <col />

Comment: BTW, this doesn't work hardly at all in IE8. I need it to work all the way back to IE6... so... Really sweet CSS, but not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @cmcculloh you should be thankful here is a great starting point.  You rep implies that you know SO is not to do your work.

Comment: @Eric Fortis Yep, it's definitely neat, but not what I asked for. I'm not asking for anyone to do my work for me. What I'm asking for is if anyone knows of a framework or library that digests some sort of data source (PHP Arrays or JSON) and spits out a formatted table. I only posted the image I did to show an example of the sort of output this framework should be capable of. I never asked someone to actually, by hand, create the table using HTML/CSS. That's what I was trying to avoid doing in the first place, not trying to pawn off. Again, I'm looking for a framework.

Comment: @Eric can you explain the css you used to move -10px up/down.  see this problem http://jsfiddle.net/J8Ep2/

Comment: @Eric Fortis: Yeah, I guess I kinda bodged that. Couldn't get `position:absolute` to work in a table cell.

Comment: Well, I did it by hand. http://chomperstomp.com/mfu/table.html YUCK. But it works across all browsers equally. I'm going to sprite the corners to decrease load time. If no one posts a link to a resource and you edit your answer just to state there is no resource to do this sort of thing, I'll mark yours as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt
http://jsfiddle.net/WsheP/
[image]

```
/* you may play with this in javascript to achieve your hover highlight */
table td:nth-child(2) {
   background-color: #f5772e;
   border-left: 2px solid #888;
   border-right: 2px solid #888;
 }
```

OR take a look to [this plugin](http://p.sohei.org/stuff/jquery/tablehover/demo/demo.html) for the column highlight on hover.

Notes: you'll need to add a texture to the `th` to match yours, and suit the gradients to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Wow that's really pretty. You can get the basic look of what you have there with a little css3. Look into css3 gradients, drop shadow and rounded corners. The only thing I don't think you'll be able to do is have that one row slightly higher and lower than the rest of the table.

Comment: I know how to do it using HTML5/CSS3 etc, I just don't *want* to do it, lol. It's going to be a pain in the ass and I want to just use a library or something to have it generate it for me so that when I want to add a new row/column or take one away it won't be such a hassle.

Comment: @cmcculloh: The whole point in CSS is that you don't have to change it when a new row or column is added.

Comment: Yes. I suppose I should have explained more clearly. I want to describe the table contents in, like, JSON or something, and then have it create itself. I don't want to deal with the HTML/CSS at all.